# docker inspect --format '{{.NetworkSettings.Networks.nat.IPAddress}}' sql1 returns '<no value>'

Tags: sql-server, windows, docker, networking, sqlcmd

I have installed [SQL Server container images with Docker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-docker?view=sql-server-ver15&pivots=cs1-powershell) but if I run:

```
docker inspect --format '{{.NetworkSettings.Networks.nat.IPAddress}}' sql1
```

as result I receive:

```
'<no value>'
```

[image]

This is quite odd because there are several [guides online](https://nexxtjump.com/2017/12/12/step-by-step-guide-to-run-sql-server-in-a-windows-docker-container/) and they all refer to this command as something that should work out of the box.

Overall SQL Server in installed and I can query databases through `sqlcmd` **within** the docker container. While if I use `sqlcmd` from **outside** the docker container I cannot connect to it.

So SQL Server is up and running but apparently the network is not setup correctly. But I see the port is setup: `0.0.0.0:1433->1433/tcp`

[image]

Is this because I'm running Docker on Windows Home edition?

[image]

Comment: That `docker inspect` command is a very low-level debugging command; you shouldn't ever need it.  If you've correctly used the `docker run -p` option, and you can run Docker Desktop, you should be able to access `localhost:1433` (the first `-p` port number) without picking apart Docker internals.